# Solving second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have such differential equation: $y'' + 8y' - 2y = x^{2002}$. I tried to solve it, but $x^{2002}$ makes everything harder. Even Wolfram couldn't solve it properly. I need a detailed solution if it's exist so I'm asking for help.

Comment: Did you solve the homogeneous part? Find the particular solution after that.

Comment: Try following the procedures at https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx, and start deducing all the coefficients term by term -- very tedious if the particular solution exist though, since the RHS is a 2002-degree polynomial of $x$.

Comment: Quite frankly do not bother calculating the particular solution for $x^{2002}$, it will be a polynomial of degree $2002$ with potentially huge coefficients... Whoever asked this question is a tormentary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

$$y′′+8y′−2y=x^{2002} \tag{1}$$

Let's start by defining the general solution, which has the form:
$$y_g=y_h+y_p \tag{2}$$
where $y_h$ is the general solution for the homogeneous part and $y_p$ is a particular solution for the not-homogeneous part.

So formulate the homogeneous general solution which has the form
$$y_h = y_1 + y_2 \tag{3}$$
$$y_h = C_1e^{k_1x} + C_2e^{k_2x} \tag{3.1}$$

So

$$y′′+8y′−2y=0$$
$$k = \frac{-8 \pm \sqrt{8^2 -4\cdot(-2)}}{2}$$
$$k_1 = -4+3\sqrt{2}$$$$k_2=-4-3\sqrt{2}$$

---

Since the $x^{2002}$ makes the classical method of undetermined coefficients impractical, we are going to use the method of variation of parameter to solve the ODE.

So, we need to find $y_p$, which according to the method and from expression $(3)$, has the form $$y_p = u(x)\cdot y_1 + v(x)\cdot y_2 \tag{4}$$

Now we need to find the arbitrary functions $u$ and $v$. To achieve this, we are going to differentiate $y_p$

$$y'_p = (u'\cdot y_1 + v'\cdot y_2) + (u\cdot y'_1 + v\cdot y'_2) \tag{5}$$

From here, just to simplify the calculus, we are going to make the condition that
$$(u'\cdot y_1 + v'\cdot y_2) = 0 \tag{6}$$
So
$$y'_p=(u\cdot y'_1 + v\cdot y'_2) \tag{7}$$
$$y''_p=(u'\cdot y'_1 + v'\cdot y'_2) + (u\cdot y''_1+ v\cdot y''_2)\tag{8}$$

We already know that $y_p$ is a particular solution for the ODE $(1)$, so  we can replace $y'' = y''_p$ ,     $y' = y'_p$ ,     $y = y_p$

Replace $(4), (7), (8)$ in $(1)$
$$(u'\cdot y'_1 + v'\cdot y'_2) + (u\cdot y''_1+ v\cdot y''_2) + 8(u\cdot y'_1 + v\cdot y'_2) -2(u\cdot y_1 + v\cdot y_2) = x^{2002}$$

Taking common factor $u, v$

$$u(y''_1+8\cdot y'_1-2\cdot y_1) + v(y''_2+8\cdot y'_2-2\cdot y_2) + (u'\cdot y'_1 + v'\cdot y'_2)= x^{2002} \tag{9}$$

Now, look again expression $(3)$ and look at the first two parenthesis of $(9)$, you have there two particular solutions for the homogeneous ODE, so you can equal them to $0$ and all that expression $(9)$ would simplify to:

$$(u'\cdot y'_1 + v'\cdot y'_2)= x^{2002} \tag{10}$$

So now, we have two unknowns $u', v'$ and two simplified equations $(6), (10)$

$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      u'\cdot y_1 + v'\cdot y_2 = 0\\
      u'\cdot y'_1 + v'\cdot y'_2= x^{2002}
    \end{cases}\,.
\end{equation} \tag{11}
$$

You can solve this system using the method you found easier, I would use the Cramer's rule:

$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1 & y_2&0 \\ y'_1&y'_2&x^{2002}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$u'=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}0 & y_2 \\ x^{2002}&y'_2\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}y_1 & y_2 \\ y'_1&y'_2\end{vmatrix}} \tag{12}$$

$$v'=\frac{\begin{vmatrix} y_1&0 \\ y'_1&x^{2002}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}y_1 & y_2 \\ y'_1&y'_2\end{vmatrix}} \tag{13}$$

From $(12)$

$$u' = -\frac{y_2\cdot x^{2002}}{y_1\cdot y'_2 - y_2\cdot y'_1} $$

$$u' = -\frac{C_2e^{k_2x}\cdot x^{2002}}{C_1e^{k_1x}\cdot C_2k_2e^{k_2x} - C_2e^{k_2x}\cdot C_1k_1e^{k_1x}} $$

$$u' = -\frac{x^{2002}}{C_1e^{k_1x}\cdot k_2 - C_1k_1e^{k_1x}} $$

$$u' = -\frac{x^{2002}}{C_1e^{k_1x}\cdot (k_2 -k_1)} $$

$$u = -\frac{1}{C_1\cdot (k_2 -k_1)}\int{\frac{x^{2002}}{e^{k_1x}}dx} $$

From $(13)$

$$v' = -\frac{y_1\cdot x^{2002}}{y_1\cdot y'_2 - y_2\cdot y'_1} $$

$$v' = -\frac{C_1e^{k_1x}\cdot x^{2002}}{C_1e^{k_1x}\cdot C_2k_2e^{k_2x} - C_2e^{k_2x}\cdot C_1k_1e^{k_1x}} $$

$$v' = -\frac{x^{2002}}{C_2k_2e^{k_2x} - C_2e^{k_2x}\cdot k_1} $$

$$v' = -\frac{x^{2002}}{C_2e^{k_2x}\cdot(k_2 - k_1)} $$

$$v = -\frac{1}{C_2\cdot (k_2 -k_1)}\int{\frac{x^{2002}}{e^{k_2x}}dx} $$

Comment: Why is $u' \cdot y_1 + v' \cdot y_2 = 0$?

Comment: @Voizz It is for simplify the calculus process, and then use it in the system of equation $(11)$. Actually, I don't know if there is something more behind $u′\cdot y_1+v′\cdot y_2=0$. However, I updated the answer to show $u$ and $v$ calculus process.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a non-homogeneous equation. First of all, you need to find the Indicial equation of the homogeneous equation and find the solution for the homogeneous solution. Then, you can use the variation of parameters method.
the variation of parameters method suggests that $$y=y_1(x)u_1(x)+y_2(x)u_2(x)+...+y_n(x)u_n(x)$$ whereas $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$ are the solutions of the homogeneous equation and $u_1(x),u_2(x),...,u_n(x)$ such that:
$$u_1'(x)y_1(x)+u_2'(x)y_2(x)+...u_n'(x)y_n(x)=0$$
$$u_1'(x)y_1'(x)+u_2'(x)y_2'(x)+...u_n'(x)y_n'(x)=g(x)
$$
Note that $g(x)$ is the non-homogenous variable, here it's $x^{2002}$.
Also,
$$Y=Y_h+Y_p$$

hope this was helpful.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).